# RavenDB MoreLikeThis - understanding results

Tags: lucene, ravendb

I'm using Lucene's MoreLikeThis function with RavenDB, very much as per the docs:

```
MyDocument[] docs = session
.Advanced
.MoreLikeThis<MyDocument>(
    "Documents/MoreLikeThis",
    null,
    new MoreLikeThisQuery
    {
        IndexName = "Documents/MoreLikeThis",
        DocumentId = "Document/1",
        Fields = new[] { "Body" },
    });
```

It's performing quite well - some of the results are clearly similar. Others less apparently so. But I can't see any way to understand why a given match is returned - I have only an array of `MyDocument`.

Is there any way to get a better insight into the response? Some sort of similarity "score" or measure?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [sorting documentation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/querying/sorting), the score should be in the document's metadata under `Temp-Index-Score`.

Lucene also provides methods to get a more granular understanding of how that score was arrived at using [`IndexSearcher.explain`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain-org.apache.lucene.search.Query-int-). I couldn't find any reference to ravendb exposing the explanation, but wanted to mention it in case I just missed it.